# iptables - allowing access to only a single port on different subnet

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, port-forwarding

I've got a OpenVPN server up and running, currently allowing to route all traffic between the VPN (10.8.0.0/24) and the LAN (192.168.2.0/24) network. My iptables look as follows:

```
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.8.0.0/24' -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.26
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.2.0/24' -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

192.168.2.26 & 10.8.0.1 are the interfaces on the VPN-Server.

I am now looking to narrow it quite a bit down and allow only specific target for specific users.
One example:

I want the user with the IP 10.8.0.10 to only have access to 192.168.2.100 on port 8080, and nothing else in the LAN subnet. After tons of googling I tried some wild combinations of SNAT and DNAT, but didn't find the solution.

How can I implement the above scenario?

Comment: I think you should rework that complete FORWARD between the 2 nets and restrict there. This is a FILTER table issue, not NAT. Also consider that OpenVPN could help in restricting routes, but you should use CCD per user configuration, and still would not prevent user from manually setting static routes.